# Asymptotic stability of  semi-trivial solution and  existence of a nontrivial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Thank's amWhy!

I pray to some kind soul to help me on the theory of bifurcation: In the article of Tao Peng titled: "*Bifurcation Behavior of a Cohen-Grossberg Neural Network of two Neurons with impulsive Effects*" They are the system of differential equations:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
x′(t)= &ax(t)(px(t)+hf(x(t))+kf(y(t))+C_1)\\
y′(t)= &by(t)(qy(t)+uf(x(t))+vf(y(t))+C_2)
\end{array}
$$
It states that the existence of two *semi- trivial solutions*; that is (x(t),0) and (0,y(t)) which is *asymptotically stable*, implies the existence of a *nontrivial solution* of the written system above.

In other word, what is the relationship  between the asymptotic stability of the semi-trivial solution and the existence of a nontrivial solution?